# Django | save() no guarda el nuevo valor 3 en la base de datos

Tags: django, django-models

Siendo el valor actual 1, ¿por qué no modifica el valor de 1 a 3? ¿Qué hago mal?

Shell:

```
>>> a = UserAnswers.objects.filter(id=1)
>>> a[0].correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion
1
>>> a[0].correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion=3
>>> a[0].save
<bound method Model.save of <UserAnswers: 1>>
>>> a[0]
<UserAnswers: 1>
>>> a[0].correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion
1
```

Model:

```
class UserAnswers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    modality = models.ForeignKey(Modality,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    numberQuestion = models.IntegerField('Número pregunta',null=True,blank=True)
    correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta correctamente',null=True,blank=True)
    wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta incorrectamente',null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué utilizas el índice `a[0]` en lugar de la propiedad del objeto `a.correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion`?

Answer (score 1):

El método `save()` nunca fue llamado. Deberías probar con `a[0].save()`.